# (Adobe Acrobat) Exclude search bar contents from search in javascript search query

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have an Adobe Interactive PDF, built in inDesign.

The document has a search bar that is meant to search the document, which it does successfully.

Problem: The search results include the contents of the search bar. Since the search bar is on every page, this ends up with a ton of arbitrary search results.

Example: Searching for "hello" will bring up all the instances of "hello" as well as the instances of "hello" in the search bar, which is on every single page.

[Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewZD7.png)
[Javascript Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJzs0.png)

The javascript search query I'm running is currently:

```
var textToSearch = this.getField("search1").valueAsString;
if (textToSearch!="") search.query(textToSearch, "ActiveDoc");
```

I want to exclude the contents of the search bar from my search, how best to execute?

**EDIT:** Replaced "search1" Field with blank string, now search field is not included with search results. But how do I use "Doc.delay" and write "textToSearch" back into the "search1" Field

Updated Code:

```
var textToSearch = this.getField("search1").valueAsString;
var eraseStr = this.getField("search1").value ="";
if (textToSearch!="") search.query(textToSearch, "ActiveDoc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the field value to an empty string ("") before executing the search since you can't control exactly what in the PDF will be searched. However, just after getting the value for textToSearch, and before setting the field value to blank, you can set the Doc.delay property to true. That will prevent the field appearance from being redrawn until you set it back to false. Then after you execute the search, set the field value back to textToSearch, set the Doc.delay property to false and... hopefully... nothing will appear to have changed for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I understand how to replace the field value to an empty string before executing the search. Now thankfully the results of the search bar are replaced with an empty string and not included in the search results. However I'm confused at how to write the textToSearch back into "search1". Would you elaborate on "setting the Doc.delay property to true" I understand how to set delay to true but what would be called in this case, the ActiveDoc? Where is "Doc" defined? Thank you so much

Comment: The code may get a bit wonky in this response but here goes... To set the value of the field back, use - this.getField("search1").valueAsString = textToSearch; - To set the delay property, use "this", in the general context, that's the current document so it'd be - this.delay = true; - or - this.delay = false;